# Can't understand the input and the result in Serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

As far as I know, the role of serializer is translating the some special objects into python-native object, or other way around.

In the following code, the input data(from the request.data) is orginally a non-python data, as the http request is done by JSON format.
And after that, we get native python data in the 2nd stage(you can see in the comment). But the weird part is, you de-serialize again, which makes data back to the data non-native python format. I think this is totally redundant.

Could anyone explain why we do such things?

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    renderer_classes = (UserJSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    # 1st step 
    # 'request.data' would be JSON format, 
    # since JS or other front-end sends data in JSON format
    def post(self, request):

        #2nd step
        #Here, we can get a native python data - dictionary
        user = request.data.get('user',{}) #Here

        #3rd step          
        #putting keyword arguments in serializer 
        #would return the de-serialized object,
        #that is, a non-native python object.
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user) 

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step converts JSON object to a dictionary, but beyond that it doesn't do any other conversion.  Anything in there that should represent dates, floating point numbers, etc will be represented as a string.  That's where the serializer comes in, in this case de-serializing.  In the third step, validation is applied to make sure that the received information is correct.  If this were a normal post, creating a new object, then it would be saved to the database, but in this case the goal is simply validation.  Finally, the object is returned to JSON for the response.  In this special case, that final "conversion" would not be necessary, because nothing changed on the model, but note that nothing is really happening because `serializer.data` simply holds the data that were input in the constructor.